# When username changes on table register get only last username in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is my table `tbl_register` on MySQL database

```
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
| sDateTime           | sRegisterAccount | sNewRegisterAccount | sID |
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
| 2019-11-27 18:52:00 | 116019           | NULL                |   1 |
| 2017-08-05 14:01:00 | 030270           | 116019              |   2 |
| 2020-04-01 14:36:00 | 542116           | NULL                |   3 |
| 2018-10-30 18:36:00 | 000647           | 542116              |   4 |
| 2019-03-07 14:19:00 | 115286           | NULL                |   5 |
| 2020-02-17 23:16:00 | 170134           | NULL                |   6 |
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
```

On this table `tbl_register` are also recorded any username changes in the column `sNewRegisterAccount`

e.g.

```
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
| sDateTime           | sRegisterAccount | sNewRegisterAccount | sID |
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
| 2020-04-01 14:36:00 | 542116           | NULL                |   3 |
| 2018-10-30 18:36:00 | 000647           | 542116              |   4 |
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
```

in the column `sRegisterAccount` the old account value `000647`

in the column `sNewRegisterAccount` the new account value `542116`

I need get only last value of `sNewRegisterAccount` as return

```
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
| sDateTime           | sRegisterAccount | sNewRegisterAccount | sID |
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
| 2019-11-27 18:52:00 | 116019           | NULL                |   1 |
| 2020-04-01 14:36:00 | 542116           | NULL                |   3 |
| 2019-03-07 14:19:00 | 115286           | NULL                |   5 |
| 2020-02-17 23:16:00 | 170134           | NULL                |   6 |
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
```

I've tried without success this query

```
mysql> SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    `tbl_register` A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        sRegisterAccount,
        MAX(sDateTime) LastDatetimeForNode
    FROM
        `tbl_register`
    GROUP BY
        sRegisterAccount
) B ON A.sRegisterAccount = B.sRegisterAccount
AND A.sDateTime = B.LastDatetimeForNode;

+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
| sDateTime           | sRegisterAccount | sNewRegisterAccount | sID |
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
| 2019-11-27 18:52:00 | 116019           | NULL                |   1 |
| 2017-08-05 14:01:00 | 030270           | 116019              |   2 |
| 2020-04-01 14:36:00 | 542116           | NULL                |   3 |
| 2018-10-30 18:36:00 | 000647           | 542116              |   4 |
| 2019-03-07 14:19:00 | 115286           | NULL                |   5 |
| 2020-02-17 23:16:00 | 170134           | NULL                |   6 |
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
6 rows in set
```

what am I doing wrong?

please, can you help me?

structure table `tbl_register` below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_register`;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_register` (
  `sDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sRegisterAccount` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sNewRegisterAccount` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of tbl_register
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `tbl_register` VALUES ('2019-11-27 18:52:00', '116019', null, '1');
INSERT INTO `tbl_register` VALUES ('2017-08-05 14:01:00', '030270', '116019', '2');
INSERT INTO `tbl_register` VALUES ('2020-04-01 14:36:00', '542116', null, '3');
INSERT INTO `tbl_register` VALUES ('2018-10-30 18:36:00', '000647', '542116', '4');
INSERT INTO `tbl_register` VALUES ('2019-03-07 14:19:00', '115286', null, '5');
INSERT INTO `tbl_register` VALUES ('2020-02-17 23:16:00', '170134', null, '6');
```

**update**

expected results

```
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
| sDateTime           | sRegisterAccount | sNewRegisterAccount | sID |
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
| 2019-11-27 18:52:00 | 116019           | NULL                |   1 |
| 2020-04-01 14:36:00 | 542116           | NULL                |   3 |
| 2019-03-07 14:19:00 | 115286           | NULL                |   5 |
| 2020-02-17 23:16:00 | 170134           | NULL                |   6 |
+---------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----+
```

Comment: what is your actual expected results from a query for this dataset?

Comment: @danblack please see **update** in question. thanks

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl_resister WHERE sNewRegisterAccount IS NULL`. If that isn't right the dataset has insufficient differentiation and/or "last value of sNewRegisterAccount" is too ambiguous for me.